# Postman - Unable to send Post Twilio API request

Tags: post, postman, twilio

URL: `https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{{Twilio_ACCOUNT_SID}}/Messages.json`

I am trying to send a Post request using Twilio "send SMS API" in Postman. When I run the request I encounter:

```
{
    "code": 21604,
    "message": "A 'To' phone number is required.",
    "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21604",
    "status": 400
}
```

I am using a free trial account. The "To" Number works fine in Twilio and is validated. I have `x-www-form-urlencoded` selected in the body of the Post Request in Postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It complains about `To` missing not it being not validated, check your request configuration in Postman.

The *Authorisation* section should look like this:
[image: authorisation section]

And the *Body* section like this:
[image: body section]

Make sure that you call your key `To` (that is uppercase `T` and lowercase `o`) and that you provide a [E.164](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-e164) formatted number.

Comment: I created a variable for the Auth token, and account SID at the root folder, selected basic Auth as the authentication method so that all request will be authenticated in the collection. The “To” key and phone number format is correct +1240755..... I’m using my personal cell. In Twilio you have to validate the phone number receiving the message (my cell). That was what I was referring to in regards to “validated” from my previous post. I am following a video on API’s for beginners and I am very careful to follow the instructors steps very closely. I know its right under my nose.

Comment: I honestly feel very foolish. I had the Get command selected instead of "Post". Alot of hours spent on this. And it was right under my nose. You will still get the credit because everything you mentioned exist in this request.