# Twilio Authentication Error - No credentials provided

Tags: authentication, twilio, credentials

I have to trigger sms via Twilio using soapUI and the rest URL is
https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Messages.json
But the response is always comes as below:
{
"code": 20003,
"message": "Authentication Error - No credentials provided",
"more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20003",
"status": 401
}

Please help in resolve this issue.
I am also not sure what should be the request JSON body as nowhere it is mentioned in Twilio documentation.

Comment: can you include any code or screenshots? Where are you including your credentials or the `to` and `from` phone #? Did you check the `curl` code in the SMS docs? https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages

Comment: I am looking for the JSON request, in the  twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages I dont see any JSON request where I can pas from /to phone number /My SID and Auth token

Comment: This does not look like JSON request                                                                                        --data-urlencode "Body=Hello from Twilio" ^
                --data-urlencode "From=YOUR_TWILIO_NUMBER" ^
                --data-urlencode "To=+myphonenumer" ^
                -u $SID:$Auth

Comment: is this a JSON request?                                                                                                            
    {
"Body":"Hello from Twilio",
"From":"+15xxxxx53",
"To":"+44xxxxx975" 
}

Comment: @lizziepika pls help me on this

Comment: I've never used soapUI, but it looks like it's like Postman? 
This is what it'd look like in Postman https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66776350/postman-unable-to-send-post-twilio-api-request

Comment: @lizziepika  I understood the post man and added authorisation, now I am getting this error   {
   "code": 21604,
   "message": "A 'To' phone number is required.",
   "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21604",
   "status": 400
}            Any idea?

Comment: who are you texting? the SO answer above includes To, From, and Body which are required to send a SMS via Twilio

Answer (score 1):

The error message "No credentials provided" usually means that you didn't supply any credentials to your request.
From your comments above, it looks like you try to access the environment variables `SID` and `Auth`. My guess is that they are missing, can you run the following commands from the same terminal session to check if they are set properly?

MacOS, Linux:

```
echo $SID
echo $Auth
```

Windows:

```
echo %SID%
echo %Auth%
```

If you don't see the credentials of your account there, please follow this [post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/01/how-to-set-environment-variables.html) to see how you can set the environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me: Use the `-u` flag with your accountSID and authToken.

```
curl https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{accountSID}/Messages/{messageSID}.json  -u {accountSID}:{authToken}
```

[Twilio Endpoint](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#fetch-a-message-resource)